# Plotting a transcendental equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I would like to get this graphic:

[image]

from [this](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.250401) article. Here $\kappa$ and $\varepsilon_{dd}$ are related by:

```
ekappa[k_, edd_, l_] := 
 3*k*edd ((l^2/2 + 1) fs[k]/(1 - k^2) - 1) + (edd - 1) (k^2 - l^2)
```

where $f_s(\kappa)$ is given by:

```
fs[k_] := (1 + 2 k^2)/(1 - k^2) - 
  3 k^2*ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - k^2]]/(1 - k^2)^(3/2)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
g[edd_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[ekappa[k, edd, 0.5], {k, 0}]
Plot[g[edd], {edd, 0, 1.6}]
```

but I do not get the graphic. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like k=1 will give you a problem, as well as any k>1.
Therefore I would change the starting value and search region for `k` in `FindRoot`.

```
g[edd_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[ekappa[k, edd, 0.5], {k, 0.5, 0.01, 0.99}]
```

Notice that this returns a rule, rather than a value:

```
g[1]
```

> {k -> 0.174197}

One way to get around this is to plot `k/.g[edd]`

```
Plot[k /. g[edd], {edd, 0, 1.6}]
```

[image]

An alternative is to redefine `g` to return a value

```
g2[edd_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[ekappa[k, edd, 0.5], {k, 0.5, 0.01, 0.99}][[1, 2]]
g2[1]
```

> 0.174197

```
Plot[g2[edd], {edd, 0, 1.6}]
```